# How to set corret path to my css,img and other files

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi i using this article as my app base.
https://blogs.msdn.com/hammett/archive/2009/04/23/mef-and-asp-net-mvc-sample.aspx
In my UI.master file i show images by `<%= Url.Content("~/Content/Shared/Images/logo.png")`
In my LoginExtension.dll i have AccountControler and all ok.
But when i try to write in web.config:

```
<authorization>
     <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

I show my login page without images,css files and js, its seems like invalid path. To show images i delete
Url.Content and write only image name...
How can i fix it ? What i do wrong?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the `authorization` tag you are allowing only authenticated users to access those resources. I would recommend you using the `[Authorize]` attribute on your controllers/actions to define authorization instead of using this tag.